# Sharepoint event handler not firing

Tags: sharepoint, content-type, event-handling

I have created an event handler for ItemAdded so that when an item is added on the site, my code checks to see if it's a folder. If it is, it should change the content type of that folder to a custom content type.

The event isn't firing, so I was wondering if I'm doing it the right way and/or in the right place. Here is my code:

```
public class ItemAddedHandler : SPItemEventReceiver
{
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);

    SPListItem listItem = properties.ListItem;
    SPList list = properties.ListItem.ParentList;
    SPContentType contentType;

    if (listItem.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder &&
       (list.Title == "Apps" || list.Title == "Data" || list.Title == "Public"))
    {
        contentType = list.ContentTypes["Custom Folder"];

        listItem["Content Type"] = contentType.Name;
        listItem["Content Type ID"] = contentType.Id.ToString();
        listItem.SystemUpdate();
    }
}
}
```

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong to accomplish this task. Thanks very much in advance.

As requested, the feature was adding with the following method:

1. Signed and compiled above code and copied DLL to server
2. Copied DLL to GAC
3. Created folder: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\SPEventHandler
   4.Created Feature.xml using GUID generated with Visual Studio:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <Feature Scope="Web" 
     Title="Added Event Handler" 
     Id="{27C2FDFF-ADA0-4984-955C-6448E182FA88}" 
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
     <ElementManifests>
       <ElementManifest Location="Elements.xml"/>
     </ElementManifests>
   </Feature>
   ```

5.Created Elements.xml using PublicKeyToken of DLL in GAC and ListTemplateID for working with a document library (101):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <Receivers ListTemplateId="101">
        <Receiver>
          <Name>AddedEventHandler</Name>
          <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
          <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
          <Assembly>SPEventHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
              PublicKeyToken=f2e7de6c4a924a03</Assembly>
          <Class>SPEventHandler.ItemAddedHandler</Class>
          <Data></Data>
          <Filter></Filter>
        </Receiver>
      </Receivers>
    </Elements>
```

1. Ran the following command on the server:

   > stsadm -o installfeature -filename SPEventHandler\Feature.xml
2. On the site (SP 2007), Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Modify All Site Settings -> Site features and activated "Added Event Handler"

After these steps, creating a new item in a list on this site does not seem to do anything, including writing to the event log, so I'm wondering if it is even getting run at all.

Thanks

Comment: I know this is a programming question, but it might be worth mentioning that you may get a better response here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah I've been trying there too.  Thanks.

Comment: I feel your pain I did sharepoint for a little while and there aren't enough resources or people who know a lot about it.  You get a mix of admins, some developers, etc.

Comment: Please show the code/configuration how you register your receiver.

Comment: I have edited the question to include steps on my deployment process.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  My custom content type needed to be enabled for the document library before an item could be given that content type.  Thanks everyone for your responses.